# Replace Android Screen Lock

Tags: android

I've made an app that has the unlock formatting that I want, but I don't know how to make it so that I can select that as the device security screen lock, or even if it is possible.

At the minute I have it so that when the phone is unlocked, the unlock app starts - however there is always a slight delay, and the app toolbar is visible at the top for a short period of time.

I've looked around for a very long time and not been able to find any resources on this other than with what I've already done, any help would be greatly appreciated.

(If it helps, the device I'm developing for is using Android 6.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a custom screen lock?
This may help.
https://github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp

Comment: Thanks - I did look at that and try to use it, but had a variety of errors. Currently I have the project set up but get the error `Window type can not be changed after the window is added.`, to which I can't find a resolution for. Also i don't know if that fully overrides it - for instance, my phone has a fingerprint lock, with an alternative pattern lock (which I can force on or off).

Answer (score 0):

Okay in the LockScreenApp Activity class

every method call in the onAttachedWindow method needs to be moved to the onCreate method